# Signal assignment in VHDL process

Tags: vhdl

I have a question regarding signal assignments in a process:
How long is each signals life interval?

Say i have this process:

```
process(T)
begin
    if T(0) = '1' then
        x<='1';
    elsif T(1) = '1' then
        y<='0';
    end if;
end process ;
```

and T is incremented every cycle.
Will the signal `X` remain '1' in the second run of the process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A signal keeps its value until it is assigned another one. Given that your code only ever assigns `'1'` to `x` and `'0'` to `y`, they will keep these values forever after the first time they are assigned.